# Django redirect /D/<anything> to /d/<anything>

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm looking for a way to redirect any url that start with `/D/` to the same URL with lowercased `/d/`.

`/D/<anything_including_url_params>`

to

`/d/<anything_including_url_params>`

I literally only want to redirect urls that start with `/D/` - not `/DABC/` etc...

The suffix can also be empty, eg. `/D/` > `/d/`

Is there a way to do that in Django? It is for a third-party app with urls included in projects urls.

The alternative is to use `re_path` and change:

```
path("d/", include(...))
```

to

```
re_path(r"^[dD]/$", include(...))
```

but I'd rather do a redirect instead of this.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use my answer and override the `get_redirect_url` function? Maybe if you include the next set of urls I can help more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a view that directs with:

```
# some_app/urls.py

from django.views.generic import RedirectView

# …

urlpatterns = [
    path('d/', include(…)),
    path(
        'D/<path:path>',
        RedirectView.as_view(
            url='/d/%(path)s', query_string=True, permanent=True
        ),
    ),
]
```

Note that a redirect will however always result in a GET request, so even if the original request to `D/something` is a POST request for example, it will make a GET request to `d/something`.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't use a RedirectView at all?

As per the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

You can register this as the literal `/D/` but redirect to `/d/` using the view name and passing on and args or kwargs.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that it is "include(someapp.urls)", not just one url pattern/view. So I can't use `pattern_name`. Can this be solved by RedirectView?